# Remove spacing between Histogram columns on date-time axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a stock price chart with variance along xAxis (its a special chart). I want to plot this variance as histogram.I can draw it successfully but I can't get rid of the space between histogram columns. fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Lng1w0my/1/ (click on price series to generate histogram)

[image]

I have set

`groupPadding: 0,
 pointPadding: 0`

but doesn't work.

I tried a simpler fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hpdru52b/1/ And this one works fine.
[image]

I can't find what is the difference.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `ordinal` option to `false`:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ush37qox/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis